# Get the Echo value from other page while a script in that file still running

Tags: php

**Page1.php :**

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){$("#btn_submit").click(function(){
      var key = $("#key").val();
      $('#mailing1').html("<a href='#' ><i class='fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw'></i> &nbsp;Please wait </a>");
      $.post("page2.php", {key : key}, function(data){$("#mailing1").html(data)
;});});});
</script>
</head>
<body>Enter Your Key Value<input id="key" type="text">
<button id="btn_submit" type="button">Click Me!</button>
<div id="mailing1"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Page2.php :**

```
<?php
include db.php;

echo $key=$_REQUEST[key];

$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `Process`(`flags`) VALUES ($key)");
$u_id= mysql_insert_id();

echo "Process Started and the Your Unique Id is :" .$u_id;
file_get_contents("http://domain.com/page3.php?$key|$u_id");

?>
```

**Page3.php :**

```
<?php
include db.php;


$str =$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

$str =explode("|",$str);

$key= $str[0];
$u_id= $str[1];

$sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Process` WHERE ProcessID=$u_id ");

$result= mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);

print_r($result);


if($key==1)
{

$count=0;
while($x==0)
{
    $sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT flags FROM `Process` WHERE U_ID=$u_id ");
    $sql2 = mysql_query("UPDATE `Process` SET count=$count WHERE U_ID=$u_id ");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1);
    $key=$row['flags'];
    if ($key==1)
    {echo "process runing";
echo $a=$a+1;
}
    if ($key==2)
    {
            $x=10;
            echo "process Stopped";
    }

    $count=$count+1;
}
}
?>
```

Desired Output :-

When the the 'Click Me' button is clicked on page1.php, Its should return the echo value in page2.php (echo "Process Started and the Your Unique Id is :" .$u_id;) and should do go to page3.php for processing.

But now the echo value in page2.php is printing only after all the process is completed in page3.php.

Kindly provide me a possible solution.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Page2.php will always wait for Page3.php, since you're calling it in the script.

Page2.php should return the u_id, and then in the javascript code post a second time to Page3.php with the u_id recently obtained.

The messages is irrelevant in Page2.php, you could easily handle that part in javascript.

So, remove this line for Page2.php:

```
file_get_contents("http://domain.com/page3.php?$key|$u_id");
```

And change your javascript code to something like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#btn_submit").click(function() {
            var key = $("#key").val();
            $('#mailing1').html("<a href='#' ><i class='fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw'></i> &nbsp;Please wait </a>");
            $.post("page2.php", {
                key: key
            }, function(data) {
              var u_id = data;
                $("#mailing1").html('Process Started and the Your Unique Id is :' + u_id);
                $.get("page3.php?key=" + u_id,
                      function ( response ) {
                         console.log( response );
                      }
                );
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @espino316 ... I want to get the $key value also from page2.php and send it to page3.php along with u_id. kindly let me know how to do it ?

Comment: You don't need to get it from Page2.php, you already have it in the javascript, here `var key = $("#key").val();`. So you have to call the Page3.php like this:   `$.get("page3.php?" + key + "|" + u_id,
                      function ( response ) {
                         console.log( response );
                      }
                );`

Comment: Thanks a lot @espino316